# Is the codomain part of the function?

Tags: functions, notation

If functions are defined as sets of ordered pairs, then how does it make sense to talk about *the* codomain of a function, or talk about a function being surjective (rather than saying something like “surjective to $X$”)?

If the codomain is actually part of the function, then does that mean that if $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and $g : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(n) = g(n) = n$, then $f \neq g$?

Comment: related: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91958/can-two-functions-with-different-codomains-be-equal)

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59432/domain-co-domain-range-of-a-function/59503#59503)